# Play MJPEG stream in iPhone using Monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, mjpeg

how to Play MJPEG stream in iPhone using Monotouch?

First i using webview to play. In iOS 5 it's playing but in iOS 6 and later version MJPEG not playing in webview.

i found Motion JPEG Image view in XCode.

https://github.com/mateagar/Motion-JPEG-Image-View-for-iOS

i try to convert the Motion JPEG Image view to Monotouch c# but i can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`? Apple doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html).

We use it for playing local video files in [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-harlem-shake/id603351246?ls=1&mt=8) and it works great.

Use it like this, make sure it is the "ViewController" and not "Controller":

```
var movieController = new MPMoviePlayerController(new NSUrl("http://yoururl.com/yourmovie.mp4"));
movieController.MoviePlayer.ShouldAutoplay = true;
movieController.MoviePlayer.SourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming;
//Show the controller modally over top another controller
PresentViewController(movieController, true, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jonathanpeppers. I try MPMoviePlayerViewController but no success. Not play a local video file. I play a live stream video or recorded video MJEPG format from online... In Xcode there is a custom control for play MJPEG format from online but not in Monotouch

Comment: You can pass any `NSUrl` to the controller's constructor, so this could be a url on a website. Did this not work for you? I can update with an example if you are having trouble.

Comment: I try this but not playing i only saw a black screen

_moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController(new NSUrl("URL"));
   _moviePlayer.View .Frame = new RectangleF (100f, 20f, 240f,180f);
    this.View .AddSubview  (_moviePlayer.View );
   _moviePlayer.Play();

Comment: See edit above, you need to use "ViewController", not "Controller".

Comment: i tried this but no success. Streaming from server should be http streaming?

Comment: Can you post the url you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Using MJPEGClient it possible to play MJPEG video with socket. I have implemented referring following sample [MJPEG](https://github.com/horsson/mjpeg-iphone) 
If have any issues get back to me.